# CSS ::before ::after width & height from attribute element

Tags: javascript, html, css

As we know element ::before can white content form string attribute in same element

ex :

```
<div class="progress">
   <span class="percentage" data-percentage="24%"></span>
</div>
```

```
.progress > .data::before {
  content: attr('data-percentage')
  ...
}
```

but is any way to dynamic width / height css from attribute

```
.progress > .data::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 1rem;
  width: attr('data-percentage');
  background: red;
}
```

i know, this issues can solve with javascript, but is there any way to solve it using css

Comment: Sadly, according to mdn docs:
The attr() function can be used with any CSS property, but support for properties other than content is experimental, and support for the type-or-unit parameter is sparse.
It's not currently possible to use an attribute like this for styles other than content.